# Convert Linq to List getting AnonymousType error

Tags: c#, linq

I have seen similar error on S/O but the fixes were not straight forward to me.

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<DTD.ManagedMPS.Core.EtchVectorShapes>'
```

What am I needing to do to pass this linq query out as my specific list?

```
public List<EtchVectorShapes> GetEtchVectors(List<ViolationType> list, List<ExcelViolations> excelViolations)
    {
        var etchVector = new List<EtchVectorShapes>();

        etchVector = (from vio in list
                        where excelViolations.Any(excelVio => vio.VioID.Formatted.Equals(excelVio.VioID.ToString()))
                            && excelViolations.Any(excelVio => vio.RuleType.Formatted.Equals(excelVio.RuleType))
                            && excelViolations.Any(excelVio => vio.VioType.Formatted.Equals(excelVio.VioType)) 
                            && excelViolations.Any(excelVio => vio.EtchVects.Any(x => x.XCoordinate.Equals(excelVio.XCoordinate)))
                            && excelViolations.Any(excelVio => vio.EtchVects.Any(y => y.YCoordinate.Equals(excelVio.YCoordinate)))

                        select new
                        {
                            EtchVectors =  vio.EtchVects  // firstOrDefault.Formatted
                        }).ToList();


        return etchVector;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to change the select to `select new EtchVectorShapes{EtchVectors = vio.EtchVects}`

You also do not need to initialize the `etchVector` variable to the new List.

Comment: Thanks,  that makes sense,  so then I mapped it all up like this  select new EtchVectorShapes
                            {
                               VioID = Convert.ToInt32(vio.EtchVects.Select(x => x.VioID)),  etc...  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

is `EtchVectorShapes` properly mapped to `excelViolations` ??? you realize that these are different types?

also like the other answers , you need to add `.ToList()` at the end of the query to make it into a List<>